# Sorting data Alpha Numeric value within a field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of numbers that all start with the first four digits being numeric, then a alpha character, then 6 numeric digits.

What is the formula that I should use to sort this field so that only the first 4 numberic digits and the alpha character are identified?

Example of value:
1059B045000

Only want to 1059B the last 6 digits are not important for this sort.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `=LEFT( text, [num_chars] )`.

Create a column with the formula `=LEFT( {cell} , 5)` where `{cell}` has the full value, then sort by this column.